# Magento Register error in checkout onepage when redirect Paypal payment and redirect back again

Tags: php, magento, paypal, checkout

i have a big problem. when i checked in register in checkout onepage page, i have done information and select Paypal payment in Payment Information, then it's redirect to Paypal page, i confirmed the amount and clicked submit.it's redirect back again and when i clicked Place Order, it's give me error "Customer email is required" seem like magento not save information account. but checkout with guest, it's success. Can anyone help me out with this? or give me idea? Please advise! Thanks in advance.